# Can you play DLC in co-op if you don't own it?

Tags: saints-row-iv

Similar to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77158/can-you-play-saints-row-3-dlc-co-op-when-only-one-of-us-bought-the-dlc) question for Saint's Row 3, can two people play the DLC missions in Saint's Row 4 if only one person owns it?

Comment: Similar?  Aren't they the same question?

Comment: I suppose they are the same question, but that one is for Saint's Row the Third.  I'm asking about Saint's Row 4.

Comment: Oh gotchya! I did not notice that - my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Saint's Row 3, you cannot play a DLC mission unless both co-op players own it.

I joined a friend who had purchased the season pass, and the DLC missions disappeared from his list.  As soon as I left they showed up again.